# Changing Fragments inside Activity through onListItemClick()

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I have this Activity which at first shows a Fragment with a list of elements. This works perfectly with this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_act);

    if(null == savedInstanceState)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ListFragment glfragment = new ListFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.listfrag1, glfragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Well I have a `ListFragment` and a `DetailFragment`. But I don't know how to do the transition when I click an element of the list. I know the `fragmentTransaction.replace()`, but I don't know WHEN to call it.

I thought I should use the `OnListItemClick()` inside the `ListFragment`, but I don't know how to use the `FragmentManager` inside the Fragment and not in the main Activity... Also I want to "export" some data to the `DetailFragment` as if it was a Intent, but it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the fragment manager inside your Fragment, simply call
`getActivity().getFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`. Implementing this in your `OnItemClickListener` should suffice.

Comment: I tried this
    @Override
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
 {
  FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  DetailFragment df = new DetailFragment();
  ft.replace(R.id.listfrag1, df);
  ft.commit();
 }   but it didn't work...

Comment: OK my problem was that my DetailFragment was a ListFragment... facepalm for me. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is:

- Define an interface with one method `listItemSelected()` with as an argument the id of the selected item
- Let your activity implement this interface
- In the [`onAttach`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach%28android.app.Activity%29) of your list fragment, take the activity and keep it as a member variable, cast to the interface type. Make sure that in the [`onDetach`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDetach%28%29) you dereference it.
- In your `onListItemClick`, call this method on your activity
- In the activity, you can now do a new fragmenttransaction, this time you need to replace instead of add the fragment
- To create your detail fragment with the correct argument (the id), use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment).

This should normally work fine.